# Django FileField generate path based on ForeignKey record's slug field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

This is for a game mod filesharing site. I have Apps Mods and Games. Each hold, you guessed it, Mods and Games!

Here is my Mods model:

```
from django.db import models
# Register storage backend TODO
def mod_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/<game>/<filename>
    # Example code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

# Create your models here.
class Mods(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    game = models.ForeignKey(
        'games.Games',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    website = models.URLField()
    repoWebsite = models.URLField()
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=mod_directory_path)
```

Here is my Games model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Games(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    website = models.URLField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

I want to autoset the mod_directory_path to the slug of the Games model.

For example, if Mod item "Dynamic War Sandbox" has a ForeignKey of a unique ID pointing to the Arma 3 game, I want the file upload path to be based on the slug of the database entry for Arma 3.

```
MEDIA_ROOT/arma-3/<filename>.
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. The only requirement is that the game already exists in your database before the mod is being created.

```
def mod_directory_path(instance, filename):
    slug = instance.game.slug
    return os.sep.join([slug, filename])
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll test this and report back if it works in a few weeks. This is my first Django project after switching over from MeteorJS. Eventually I'd want the file path to be generated based not only on game slug but also game categories, eg: MEDIA_ROOT/arma-3/addons/models/<filename>. This is a different monster entirely as I need to figure out how to do Categories based on arrays contained in the Game categories field..